# Select catalog role - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, permissions, oracle-12c

Does select_catalog_role if granted to a schema provide access only to dba tables and v$ views only and not to other schemas created for any application?

The reason i'm asking this is I need to grant select_catalog_role to some administrators but not to the application schemas where in sensitive information resides.

Comment: Don't you have a 'personal' account that you can use to verify it? Or perhaps create one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only allows access to data dictionary views, so the only security implication is that the users(s) would be able to see which objects existed in the other schemas. They would not, however, be able to actually view the data in the other schemas.

I said there was only one security implication, but another is that they would be able to view the source of any stored procedures/functions in all schemas, by viewing `DBA_SOURCE` etc.